# American Vs European Options behavior with fixed strikes and varying expiration

Tags: implied-volatility, american-options, european-options

Following is from page 10 of [Fengler (2005)](https://www.econbiz.de/archiv1/2008/58072_arbitrage-free_smoothing.pdf),  "The prices of American calls for the same strikes must be nondecreasing, Merton (1973), and in the absence of dividends, this property translates to European calls as well."
[image: snippet from Fengler (2005)]
I have read in this document [Handbook of Comp Fin](https://books.google.com/books?id=PAAAhBkeFcQC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=The%20prices%20of%20American%20calls%20for%20the%20same%20strikes%20must%20be%20nondecreasing&source=bl&ots=S4Psmv_M4l&sig=M3xrnQcrqbCHlQSQpKZflvK_DK4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtmdXyirbTAhWf8oMKHfUzALIQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=The%20prices%20of%20American%20calls%20for%20the%20same%20strikes%20must%20be%20nondecreasing&f=false) that this doesn't translate to european options since there theta can change sign, so how does no dividends affect this nature of european options.
[image: snippet from book]

Thank you.

Comment: For a European Call the Theta reverses sign only if the dividend rate q is higher that rhe risk free rate $r_f$. (So with $r_f\ge 0$ and $q=0$ you are safe.

Comment: @noob2, I missed that thought, thanks for clearing that up. I need to brush up my options basics.

Comment: ... actually I am not sure I am right.  Checking...

Comment: @noob2.  In Hull there are two cases where the theta of a long option position can be positive. 
1. ITM European put on a non-dividend paying stock
2. ITM European call on a currency with a very high interest rate

Comment: @quantfin_enthusiast Consider the following thought experiment where a dividend-paying stock is expected to pay a *very large* dividend in exactly 6M. Two European options are written on that stock. They have exactly same strike but different expiries: $T_{\pm} = 6M \pm 1day$. Which one is the most expensive? Now suppose that instead these are American options, which one is the most expensive?

Comment: @Quantuple for american call **T = 6M - 1day** will be expensive, since you can just exercise it and also get the dividend on the stock. Higher time to expiration option is expensive but due to dividend large payment european option with less time to expiry will be more expensive. So in both cases T = 6M -1 day expiration options will be more exoensive. Am i right?

Comment: No. Remember that when you are long an option you do not receive dividends... For European options: the one expiring 1 day before the ex-dividend date is more expensive than the other. Since at 6M exactly, the stock price will drop: the probability for the stock price to finish above the strike (ITM) at 6M plus 1day is smaller than before the div was paid.  For American options the situation is different. Can you see why?

Comment: Since dividend will cause price drop, (S - K) value will be higher the day before dividend but american can be exercised anytime, due to the optionality to exercise anytime, higher expiration stock will be expensive.

Comment: Exactly. You got it.